# $stateParams returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have these routes defined:

```
    .state('sport',
      url: '/sport'
      templateUrl: '/templates/sport'
      controller: 'SportCtrl'
    )
    .state('sport.selected'
      url: '/:sport'
      templateUrl: '/templates/sport'
      controller: 'SportCtrl'
    )
```

And I have this controller trying to use the :sport param given by sport.selected state.

```
     angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('SportCtrl', ['$scope', 'ParseService', 
                   '$stateParams', function ($scope, ParseService, $stateParams) {

          var sportURL = $stateParams.sport;

      ...
    });
```

For some reason, it returns undefined when I call $stateParams.sport in the controller, even though I think I defined it in the routes. 
Why is this the case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you access the URL `/sport/12`, the `SportCtrl` will be instantiated twice: once for the state `sport`, and once for the state `sport.selected`. And for the first state, there is no parameter associated with the state, so `$stateParams.sport` is undefined.

Note that it's quite strange to use the same template for a state and a sub-state. You'll have the template embedded inside the ui-view div of the same template.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to using ui-view so this was a bit confusing for me. I ended up making a new controller and having it no longer be a substate and it works fine now.